# Arbitrary numbers operations

Tags: c#, numbers, scientific-computing

I try to create a library that makes operations with arbitrary size numbers (like ones with 50-100 digits).

I saw on Codeplex a library IntX. It works pretty well, but I want to make my own library to learn; the code in IntX is too complex for a beginner to undertand I think.

So, could anyone help me with the algorithm for summing to numbers by summing each digit in them and returning the sum as a string?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If off-the-shelf libraries are too difficult for you to understand yet, why not start by implementing arithmetic as you learned to do it by hand in school -- take the two strings representing your long integers, 'add' the rightmost 'digits', then carry on leftwards ?  Once you have addition done, think about multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

You could explore `System.Numerics.BigInteger` methods via ILSpy for example.